# AWS pvc dynamic provisioning with ReadWriteMany

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

My goal is to attach a dynamic volume claim to a deployment on EKS cluster, I am using this tutorial
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/persistent-storage-for-kubernetes/

My manifests are storage class, volume claim and a deployment : ( Same as from tutorial)

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-XXXX
  directoryPerms: "700"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: debug-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: debug-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debug-app
        component: debug-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ubuntu:20.04
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: debug-app
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: 
          - sleep 3650d
        #command: ["/bin/sh","-c", "sleep 365d"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 16Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
      - name: persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: efs-claim-1
```

Storage class is well created, but

```bash
NAME     PROVISIONER       RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
efs-sc   efs.csi.aws.com   Delete          Immediate           false                  5m17s
```

persistent volume claim is on `pending` state with the following description

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                     From                         Message
  ----     ------                ----                    ----                         -------
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  2m18s (x17 over 6m18s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

It's clear the efs storage can't create the persisted volume, I went back and tried with newly created efs storage following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

But the same issue persisted,

Any possible fixes here please?
Thanks

PS: Just mentioning here, I'm using no Fargate Profile

Comment: You need to provision the EFS file system before you create the PVC. You then need to reference the ID of the file system in your storage class, e.g. fs-XXXX. Also, be sure that the necessary SG rules are in place for you to access the file system from your pods. NFS uses port 2049.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but it was an image issue from csi driver

Answer (score 1):

> I went back and tried with newly created efs storage following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

But you didn't install the [driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html#efs-install-driver). Hence you get `...waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com"`.

Comment: csi driver was installed , but there was an image pull issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked the csi driver installation on namespace `kube-system`, which had an `ImagePullBack` error,

The tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html#efs-install-driver is mentionning an image `eks/aws-efs-csi-driver`, which doesn't exist.

> helm upgrade -i aws-efs-csi-driver
> aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver 
> --namespace kube-system 
> --set image.repository=602401143452.dkr.ecr.region-code.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver 
> --set controller.serviceAccount.create=false 
> --set controller.serviceAccount.name=efs-csi-controller-sa

The correct image name from docker hub is `amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver` https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver

I pushed this image to my repository, then re-installed csi driver with helm:

```bash
helm upgrade -i aws-efs-csi-driver aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set image.repository=${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/amazon/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.name=efs-csi-controller-sa
```

Now, volume is well attached and all is good,
Thanks,